# Why need to create vhost for localhost and for Laravel project itself

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I am new to Laravel and I wonder what is the reason to create vhost for localhost like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And then create vhost for Laravel project like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/public"
    ServerName test.me
</VirtualHost>
```

Well, it is clear in terms of the creation of vhost for Laravel project but it is unclear why to create for just localhost and is it ok if I remove it(the localhost vhost)

Comment: You could just disable the vhost for localhost and see if it works?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, hi Magnus :) yea it works if I remove localhost vhost but I would like to understand why to have one for localhost. Since all Laravel tutorials on YouTube teach to have both for localhost and for Laravel project. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: That's just a default vhost. Nothing to care about if you're not going to use `localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no technical requirement for this. Each vhost is in fact separate entity, despite the fact the share some part of `DocumentRoot` path. You do not need two virtual hosts set up to make things work in your case, nor these vhosts are connected nor depend on each other in any way. The localhost vhost is simply for your (potential) convenience but you can safely get rid of it if you do not find it that useful or needed at all.

Comment: Marcin, I wonder why would you ever want to create vhost for localhost, you know, is there any benefit or as you said "convenience" of having such vhost in projects. I hopw you will answer. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I assume it makes newbies less confused when they try to do `http://localhost/` and anything works :)

Answer (score 1):

So that you don't need to open your project in your browser like this "http://localhost/MyProject/public". It is way simpler just to type: myproject.dev, right? :)

EDIT:

And this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Is needed so that your http://localhost is still available.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (and doesn't really make much sense). The OP asks about why the `localhost`-vhost is there, not why they should add an alternative hostname.

Comment: Well yes, I missed to mention that vhost for localhost is need so your localhost is still available.